# Centering label in polygon in TileMill/CartoCSS

Tags: polygon, labeling, tilemill, cartocss, center

For some reason, labels are always placed in the bottom right of a polygon. I want them in the center of a polygon.

I tried these:

```css
text-horizontal-alignment: middle;
text-vertical-alignment: middle;
```

but it doesn't help.

I noticed a strange thing: build-in labels are centered inside a polygon, but for regular `area=yes` or `landuse=yes` they are along the line, i.e. `text-placement:interior` is not working consistently.

Full example:

```css
#labels {
    text-name: "[name]";
    text-fill: #444;
    text-face-name: 'Alfios Bold';
    text-placement: interior;
    text-size: 12pt;
}

#cemetery[building='yes'] {
    polygon-fill: #0f0;
}

#cemetery[landuse='residential'] {
    polygon-fill: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have declared somewhere rule like: `text-placements: "SE,16";`

Comment: No, I haven't declared text-placements.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using OsmPlugin, that doesn't support polygons very well :(

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but if someone stumbles upon it currently looking for the answer try

```css
text-placement-type: simple;
```